# GetValue of TextBox

Tags: c#, .net

**Project Informations**

- Windows Presentation Foundation Project
- C# as programming language

**Description**

How I can get the value from the Textbox with `GetValue()`?

When I run `GetValue(TextBox)` the following error will be printed:

> "TextBox" is a "Typ" and not available in this Context

Comment: You are not using the `MVVM` pattern like having a `ViewModel` as `DataContext` and then `Binding SomeVmProperty` in the View's `xaml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TextBox` is the *type* (class).  You need an object of that type.

```
TextBox  _myTextBox = new TextBox();
// :
// :

string text = _myTextBox.Text;
```